# inserting into table shows Duplicate entry #1062 while i am not entering primary key

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, sql-insert, mysql-error-1062

I am trying to enter set of data in to my Cycles Table ,
The structure of the table as below.

[image: Structure of the table]

When I am trying to insert the data into the table. I get error as below.

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '65535' for key 'PRIMARY''
```

My question is I am not trying to insert values into my primary key field which is **id**. then why I am getting duplication error. check my insertion query below.

I believe when auto increment field is left empty that should add values by itself. 
[image]

When I made a manual check to see weather the record exit by

```
 Select * from Cycles where id = 65535
```

`var_dump($resutls)` shows empty array and `count($resutls)` is zero

[image]

Comment: try it directly in database and let me know the output select *  from your_tablename where id =65535

Comment: Hi @JYoThI I tried that, when I var_dump it show empty array, when I `count($resutls)` the result is zero;

Comment: show your description of table using query :       desc Cycles

Comment: ` "Select * from Cycles where id = 65535";`

Comment: Please replace all your screenshots with plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All

For your suggestion.

I found the error, I have to change in my table structure for id (smallint) to id (int(11)).

The smallint datatype was not doing any increments.

[image]